# HTTP Status 404 - hello world wicket

Tags: java, eclipse, wicket

i'm create project for wicket example hello world, and i'm run to application but display page show HTTP Status 404 - and description : The requested resource () is not available.

*this my source code: HelloWorld.java*

```
package com.wicket.hello;

import org.apache.wicket.PageParameters;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label;

public class HelloWorld extends WebPage {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public HelloWorld(final PageParameters pageParameters) {
    add(new Label("message", "Hello World"));
}
}
```

*This my source code: HelloWorld.html*

```
<html>
<body>
    <span wicket:id="message">Message goes here</span>
</body>
</html>
```

*This my source code: HelloWorldApplication.java*

```
package com.wicket;

import org.apache.wicket.Page;
import org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebApplication;

import com.wicket.hello.HelloWorld;

public class HelloWorldApplication extends WebApplication {

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Page> getHomePage() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return HelloWorld.class;
    }

}
```

*This my source: web.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>WicketApp</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>HelloWorldApplication</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
          <param-value>com.wicket.HelloWorldApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>HelloWorldApplication</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

*This my source: pom.xml*

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>WicketApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>WicketApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- slf4j-log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: What URL are you requesting to receive the 404?

Comment: What is in your `context.xml` file? Path should be equal to `""`

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing the warsourcedirectory part of your pom.xml.

Is there any reason using the old 1.4.x instead of a 6.x version (forcing jdk7 means to me you're targeting an updated system)?

Comment: okey, i'm change my version wicket to 6.7.0 and my jdk7, but view in run application is same HTTP 404. what i'm wrong?

Comment: Did you removed the WarSourceDirectory part of your pom.xml, it seems weird to me ?

Answer (score 0):

add below code in your pom.xml inside build , this will add HTML files into your deployable classes folder, and your issue'll resolve

```
<resources>
<resource>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
<directory>src/main/resources</directory>
</resource>
<resource>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <directory>src/main/java</directory>
    <includes>
        <include>**</include>
    </includes>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
</resource>
```